# Strange compilation error in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

How to solve that? "Это не каталог" means "This is not a catalogue".

[image: Compilation error]

Comment: You should stop spamming with the new questions until you get your previous issues resolved as they are probably related to the incorrect project configuration.

Comment: I have solved previous questions. From now I worried only about those question.

Comment: Same error I have when trying to make any project in idea

Comment: Check your artifacts configuration, try to delete all the artifacts output from the file system and configure the new artifact from scratch following the documentation at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-artifacts.html. If the issue remains, provide a sample project to reproduce it.

Comment: Just like that. Maven clean also helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that situation MAVEN CLEAN helps.